# How do I get apache zeppelin 0.9.0

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I can't find a way to get Apache zeppelin 0.9.0 binaries. I think there used to be a download page and it was removed.
Can someone help me with that?

Thanks,
Ori

Answer (score 2):

Version 0.9.0 is not released yet.
You could check available versions at [official page](http://zeppelin.apache.org/download.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can download build from the master branch of the [apache/zeppelin](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin) by following [the guide here](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.9.0-SNAPSHOT/setup/basics/how_to_build.html). For example, i'd like to build for spark 2.4.4 hadoop 2.9 and scala 2.11, I issued a command `mvn package -DskipTests -Pbuild-distr -Pspark-2.4.4 -Phadoop-2.9 -Pscala-2.11`